# Is it possible to use chromium extensions on the new webbroswer-app?

Tags: unity

Since oxide is advertised as a chromium view on qt.
I'm wondering if it's possible to use chromium extensions on the new webbroswer-app?

(That would be great for example to use a gmail specific extension in the unity-webapps-gmail)